# How to format or truncate a scientific notation Double value to three decimal places without changing the exponent part in java

Tags: java, format, double

i need to truncate a scientific notation Double value to three decimal places without loosing the exponent part in java

input :8.97136728211456E-4

output :8.971E-4

Output can be string.
I would prefer not to use substring manipulation but using standard format

Comment: Is the decimal stored separate from the exponent? We would be better able to help of we could see your code

Comment: Double myvalue = Double.parseDouble("897136728211456") / Math.pow(10, 18)

Comment: [`String.format("%.3e", myvalue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Hi Andreas, your answer works amazingly fine with one small glitch .The output is 8.971e-04 instead of 8.971e-4. I have to check whether this is acceptable or not to tester.